# Infinite variance in the Law of large numbers

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, convergence-divergence, law-of-large-numbers

Let $(X_{n})_{n>0}$ be independent random variables, with $E(X_{n})=\mu$ and $V(X_{n})=\sigma_{i}^{2}$.

If $\sigma_{i}^{2}$. are not bounded, is it true that $\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{N} X_{n}}{N}$ converges in probability to $\mu$ when $N\to+\infty$?

If the answer is No, what would be a counter-example? If it is Yes, how can I prove it?

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: A result by Chow shows that probability 1 convergence occurs if $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sigma_i^2}{i^2} <\infty$. So, for example, it holds if $\sigma_i^2 = i^{99/100}$ for $i \in \{1, 2, 3,...\}$.  Chow actually treats a slightly more general system that can be described by martingales, the reference is:  Y. S. Chow, “On a strong law of large numbers for martingales,” Annals of Mathematical Statistics, vol. 38, no. 2, article 610, 1967.

Comment: I see the question asks about the weaker case of "convergence in probability" in which case I agree with the user251257 comment "what have you tried"? The probability 1 result is not trivial but the "in probability" result can be proven (for certain conditions on $\sigma_i^2$) directly by basic techniques, techniques that are very close to the standard proof of the weak law of large numbers for identical variances.

Comment: @Michael which is the proof you are talking about that involves the variance not being bounded?

Comment: @Lucy : I mentioned "the standard proof of the weak law of large numbers for identical variances" as the one that assumes $\{X_i\}$ are i.i.d. with finite mean and variance and invokes the Markov/Chebyshev inequality. That can easily be adapted to a case when variances can grow with $i$, under a certain condition that you can give that basically says the rate of growth is not too large.

Answer (score 1):

If the $\sigma_i^2$ increase extremely quickly, then the sample means can have large variances and prevent convergence in probability.

Concrete counterexample:

> Let $X_n \sim N(0, n^2)$. Then $\bar{X}_N := \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N X_n \sim N(0, \frac{(N+1)(2N+1)}{6N})$, so $P(|\bar{X}_N| > \epsilon)$ is strictly increasing as $N \to \infty$.

Response to comment:

> Since $\bar{X}_N / \sqrt{\frac{(N+1)(2N+1)}{6N}} \sim N(0,1)$ we have $P(|\bar{X}_N| > \epsilon) = P\left(|Z| > \epsilon/\sqrt{\frac{(N+1)(2N+1)}{6N}}\right)$. As $N \to \infty$, the quantity $\epsilon/\sqrt{\frac{(N+1)(2N+1)}{6N}}$ decreases to zero, making the probability increase.

Comment: Why is strictly increasing? How do you relationate that probability with the variance?

Comment: @Lucy See my edit. Note that it would be good for you to come up with your own counterexamples.